# can't find main(String[]) method in class: InvalidNameException

Tags: java

```
class InvalidNameException extends Exception{}
class Slip11
{
    String nm;
    Slip11(String nm)
    {
        this.nm=nm;
    }
    void display()
    {
        System.out.println("EMPLOYEE NAME : "+nm+" is valid");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception  
    {
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println("ENTRE NAME OF EMPLOYEE");
        String name=br.readLine();

        try
        {
            int len=name.length();
            int flag=0;
            for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
            {
                char ch=name.charAt(i);
                if(Character.isLowerCase(ch)|| Character.isUpperCase(ch))
                {
                    flag=1;
                }
                else
                {
                    flag=1;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(flag==-1)
            {
                throw new InvalidNameException();
            }
            else
            {
                Slip11 s=new Slip11(name);
                s.display();
            }
        }
        catch(InvalidNameException e)
        {
            System.out.println("employee name is not valid "+name+" is  Invalid");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what's the filename?

Comment: filename is Slip11.java

Comment: You have *two* class declarations in your file. Get rid of `class InvalidNameException extends Exception{}` or move it below `class Slip11`, but inside the closing bracket for `Slip11` (if you're trying to declare an inner class).

Comment: Also use `public class Slip11`

Comment: @tasmiyashaikh, if you have named your .java file name as InvalidNameException.java, While running JRE will try to find the main(String[] args) method from that class only. So, you can also rename your .java file to the class where you mentioned main method or you move the main method into the file which you named .java file.